# "Hooks" in MVC3

Tags: c#, codeigniter, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a MVC3 project using C#, I was wondering if MVC3 has something similar to hooks in CodeIgniter (for executing code just before each ActionResult executes). I need it to update an arraylist of visited websites in the session.

EDIT: I've worked out a solution using an ActionResult, I'll post it here for reference.

**ActionFilter:**

```
public class HistoryTracker : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // ...
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HistoryTracker());
    }
```

This makes the ActionFilter always trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [ActionFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the name. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ActionFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx). This's exactly what you need